# Simultaneous Galois closure

Tags: galois-theory, fields

For a finite separable extension $L/K$ of fields, there exists a *Galois closure*, which is a finite field extension $\tilde L/L/K$ where $\tilde L/K$ is Galois. (given by the compositum of $\sigma L$, for all $K$-embeddings $\sigma\colon L\to K^\text{sep}$.)

Is anything known for an analog with multiple fields? That is,

> Given finite separable field extensions $L/K_1$ and $L/K_2$, when does there exist a finite field extension $\tilde L/L$ such that both $\tilde L/K_1$ and $\tilde L/K_2$ are Galois?

When $L/K_1\cap K_2$ is finite, one may simply take $\tilde L$ as the Galois closure of $L/K_1\cap K_2$. However, what happens when, for instance, $L=\mathbb C(x)$, $K_1=\mathbb C(x(x-1)^2)$, and $K_2=\mathbb C(x^2(x-1))$, where we have $K_1\cap K_2=\mathbb C$? (I have not been able to prove this is a counterexample, but $L/K_1\cap K_2$ being a transcendental extension seems to be an obstruction.)

One can construct such an extension $\tilde L/L$ as following, by working in a fixed separable closure $L^\text{sep}$:

1. Let $L_1$ be the Galois closure of $L/K_1$.
2. Let $L_2$ be the Galois closure of $L_1/K_2$.
3. Let $L_3$ be the Galois closure of $L_2/K_1$.
4. Let $L_4$ be the Galois closure of $L_3/K_2$.
5. ...

Then, our desired field extension $\tilde L$ will be, if it existed, $\bigcup_{n\ge1}L_n$. However, there is a priori *no reason* to believe the process above will terminate.

---

Can anything be said in the simpler case, when $L=K_1K_2$? That is,

> Given fields $K_1$ and $K_2$ with both $K_1K_2/K_1$ and $K_1K_2/K_2$ finite, when does there exist a finite field extension $\tilde L/K_1K_2$ such that both $\tilde L/K_1$ and $\tilde L/K_2$ are Galois?

Comment: Wouldn't that subgroup be $\mathrm{Gal}(L^\text{sep}/K_1K_2)$, which has fixed field $K_1K_2$?